Auth) SPA allowed URLs not taking account port
I have a NextJs V14 application running on 3020.
I am using @auth0/nextjs-auth0: 3.5
I have Allowed callback URLs populated with
http://localhost:3020/api/auth/callback,

On click the signing button I get the error message:
unauthorized_client: Callback URL mismatch. http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback is not in the list of allowed callback URLs
How do I get the Auth0 to use port 3020 instead of 3000?
